# Is this airliner-shaped lake real?

Tags: geography, utah, lakes

On a flight over Utah, I spotted a strange shape on the flight route app
on the seat LCD that looks just like an airliner:

[image: Easter Egg lake]

Not believing my eyes, I checked OsmAnd and sure enough, it's there!

Here it is on OpenStreetMap:
http://openstreetmap.org/#map=11/41.27/-111.8

Pity it was clouded over, so I couldn't see it for real...

Its Wikipedia page doesn't mention its shape:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineview_Dam

Could it be an Easter Egg or just pure coincidence?

Comment: At first I thought it was airplane's shadow.

Comment: This lake is almost begging for a plane to crash in it.  I wouldn't fly over it.

Comment: It's probably where one of the [fanless DC-8s crashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenu) 75 million years ago. You're not going to have a perfect safety record when transporting ~10 trillion people.

Comment: "a man sees what he wants to see and disregards the rest ..." la la la

Answer (score 49):

It does remotely look like an airplane as [Google Maps / Earth](https://www.google.ch/maps/place/Pineview+Dam,+Utah+84317,+USA/@41.2562807,-111.7736797,12934m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x8753a76fcb7b6b2d:0x21c9d39d146aadb?hl=en) reveals:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bird to me, well airliners are kinda oversized birds anyway.

Comment: @FurkanOmay A bird? A plane? It's super-lake!

Comment: I clearly see a Saturn V as it passes through the sound barrier.

Comment: @dot what is the split tail, then? If they are stabilisation fins, where are the thrusters?

Comment: Rocket exhaust!

Comment: It looks like a Rorschach ink-blot test to me

Answer (score 37):

It's clearly visible in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/41%C2%B015'15.8%22N+111%C2%B050'31.6%22W/@41.2662912,-111.8036385,8725m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0?hl=en), where you'll also notice that it is much larger than a real airliner.

The human brain is very good at recognizing pattern, and in your case it identified this lake loosely resembling an airliner. The phenomenon of recognizing patterns in random data is called [Apophenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia).

So in summary, there is no reason to assume this lake is not real and its shape anything other than coincidence.

Comment: Also humans can deliberate build such forms like a [city in the shape of a airplane](http://uselessk.com/facts/the-ground-plan-of-brasilia-capital-of-brazil-has-the-shape-of-an-airplane)

Comment: You say apophenia, I say [pareidolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia)

Comment: That's what I was wondering: Did the reservoir builders intentionally build it so?

Comment: @Gnubie Unlikely it was deliberate.  The humans only really choose where the dam goes; the shape of the resulting reservoir is down to the landscape provided by mother nature.

Comment: @jean sadly link is now broken :/

Comment: @MarkMayo Sadly that link got outdated try this google maps of [Brasília](https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Bras%C3%ADlia+-+Brasilia,+Federal+District/@-15.7870323,-47.9101785,12.63z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x935a3d18df9ae275:0x738470e469754a24)

Answer (score 19):

That's Pineview Reservoir.  It has a three-fingered shape (or fuselage-and-wings shape) because it was built at the confluence of several streams.  It is indeed a real body of water, but not technically a lake.

Sources:

- Firsthand experience at the reservoir
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineview_Dam
- https://www.google.com/maps/@41.2660977,-111.8092137,13z

Comment: I've been there many times.

Comment: "not technically a lake" A man-made lake is still a lake.